# Unexpected token '?' when trying to run 'npm run dev'

Tags: npm, npm-package

Can someone help me with this error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.dev (/Users/@#@!1/!@#@!/node_modules/next/dist/lib/commands.js:10:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/!@#!/!@#!!#/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next:141:28)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
```

I ran npm on a mac

Answer (score 7):

This happens, perhaps, due to incompatibility between Next.js and Node.js versions. If you upgrade your Node.js version to at least v14, it will work.

Comment: I am on node.js version `18.0.0` but this doesn't seem to work. It does download 64-bit build.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I try to run my next.js application. When I update the node version, error was gone.

You can use [nvm(node version manager)](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows#readme) to use multiple node versions in your computer.

Hope this will help to sort out your issue.